# Woocommerce adding multi products works, but doesn't pass quantity

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having an issue passing along quantity when adding multiple items to the shopping cart. I have a table setup where customers can add up to 10 skus at once. It does in fact add all 10 products to the shopping cart page, but the problem is the quantity only shows 1. I've tried a vardump with a echo on the ending cart part and it echos fine. Not really sure why it's not picking it up.

```
function process_add_products()
{
global $woocommerce;
$cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
if (!empty($_POST["add"]))
{
    if ($_POST["add"]==1)
    {
        $addprod_q = $_POST["addprod_q"];
        $addprod_id = $_POST["addprod_id"];
        foreach ($addprod_id as $k=>$pid)
        {   
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($pid, $addprod_q[$k]);
        }
        header("Location: ".$cart_url);
        die();
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are sure that `$addprod_q[$k]` is the desired quantity? If nothing is set there then `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` will default to a quantity of 1.

Comment: Yeah, when I do a echo on `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($pid, $addprod_q[$k]);`, it shows the correct id and quantity. I'm just not sure why woocommerce won't apply it. I was thinking maybe I need to adjust the cart after adding it. Like set_quantity or something.

Comment: Ok Figured out my problem, It's if you check the box Items sold Individually. It's hardcoded to only allow 1 item. So it makes buik orders of the same item not work.

Comment: #facepalm happens to everybody

Answer (score 0):

It's if you check the box Items sold Individually. It's hard coded to only allow 1